# Subtracting a 3D Sink from a 3D Cupboard-Board in ThreeJS

Tags: three.js, 3d

I have two separate obj.s - a sink and a board (the top of a bathroom-cupboard).
The sink needs to be placed on top of the board, like this:
[http://www.farline.cz/orig-image/364470b4db.jpg?c=NS0xNDkzMjk2MjIy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTjn3.jpg)
(just an examle from image-search)

However, of course, both objects overlap, so the board is still there where the hole of the sink is supposed to be.
Using a boolean to subtract the sink from the cupboard isn't enough, because it won't cut out the hollow space.

What options do I have to go about this?
Is there a way to have the sinkhole considered a part of the boolean that cuts away from the cupboard?

Btw. this needs to be done with several sinks of various shapes and measurements.
I considered adding an invisible cube with the same measurements as the sink to substract its mass from the board, but it's a highly suboptimal solution (for it'd need to be redone for every sink individually + some sinks have round shapes).

Comment: The question is too broad for a short answer. There are many ways to achieve what you want. You can ask this question on the [forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/).

Comment: @hallow: will making board - convex_hull( sink ) improve? Or some sinks "especially" unusual shape exist, where it would not work? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull