# Raycasting works only on one half of an object

Tags: three.js, 3d, raycasting

**Update**: a solution has been found, in case anyone may find themselves with the same problem.
Two things need to be done:

1. After adding the model to the scene we need to update the MatrixWorld: `scene.updateMatrixWorld();`
2. The vectors the raycaster uses have to be normalized. So we have to change two lines of code to:

   `geometry.vertices.push(v1.normalize());
   geometry.vertices.push(v2.normalize());`

---

The goal is to trace the inner outline of an obj. and extrude that outline into a new shape.
The raycasting starts in the middle of the world (0,0,0) with the obj. placed around it.

file:///D:/Mach%20Parat/raycasting/raycast_stackoverflow/raycast.html

The red lines are the visualized directions of the rays.
Everytime the rays intersect with the object, the coordinates are put into an array - based on that array, the yellow extrude-object is generated.

Problem is that only half of the rays seem to register hitting the obj.

The obj. is a teapot generated in Blender - The cup is half-full I guess.
https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/intermediary/f/8a5fae76-ef7d-4795-9d79-f9b354b893db/dcz4o34-80b02357-3fec-469a-b290-00103f83f4ba.png

Using a simple object like a sphere (default object in Blender) works fine:
https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/intermediary/f/8a5fae76-ef7d-4795-9d79-f9b354b893db/dcz4o2r-19c407a3-7b1d-458c-b39a-61189839a044.png

But only so long as the object is centered (0,0,0). Move it a few pixels and the same problem occurs:
https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/intermediary/f/8a5fae76-ef7d-4795-9d79-f9b354b893db/dcz4o2l-2c6a17f8-e3a4-464e-a022-151839581355.png

it's up for download here, if you want to check for yourself:
http://download.mach-parat.de/raycast.zip

```
            //////////////////////// Model
            var model= "models/teapot.obj";

            addObject(model);

        }


        function addObject (model){

            var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

                loader.load( model, function ( object ) {
                console.log("load");
                console.log(object);
                var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffffff, side: THREE.DoubleSide  } );

                scene.add( object );

                object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                       if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                          child.material = material;

                            child.updateMatrix(); // as needed
                        child.updateMatrixWorld(); // as needed
                          objects.push(child);
                       }
                } );

                setupRaycaster();


            });

        } 

        /////////////////////////////////// RAYCASTER AND RED LINE VISUALISATION
        function setupRaycaster(){

            var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000});
            var raylength=100;
            var count=90;

            var angle=360/count;


            for (var i=0; i<count; i++){ 

                var x=0;
                var y=0;
                var z=0;


                var v1=new THREE.Vector3( x, y, z);
                var v2=new THREE.Vector3( x+raylength*Math.cos(i*angle*Math.PI/180), y+raylength*Math.sin(i*angle*Math.PI/180), z);

                var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
                geometry.vertices.push(v1); 
                geometry.vertices.push(v2);

                var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
                scene.add( line );

                var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
                raycaster.set ( v1, v2 );


                var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects , true);
                console.log(i,intersects);
                if(intersects[0]){
                    cutOutPoints.push(intersects[0].point);
                }

            }

            console.log(cutOutPoints);



            /////////////////////////////////// YELLOW EXTRUDE GEOMETRY
            var cutOutShape = new THREE.Shape();

            if(cutOutPoints.length){// wenn cutpoints in Array
                cutOutShape.moveTo(cutOutPoints[0].x, cutOutPoints[0].y);

                for (var i=1; i<cutOutPoints.length; i++){ 
                    cutOutShape.lineTo(cutOutPoints[i].x, cutOutPoints[i].y);
                }

                var cutOutMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0xffcc00});

                var extrudeSettings = { amount: 60, bevelEnabled: false};

                var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( cutOutShape, extrudeSettings );

                var cutOutMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, cutOutMaterial );
                scene.add( cutOutMesh );
            }

        }
```

a while ago I tried to solve this original problem of cutting a sink out of a cupboard:
[Subtracting a 3D Sink from a 3D Cupboard-Board in ThreeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53834360/subtracting-a-3d-sink-from-a-3d-cupboard-board-in-threejs)

Unfortunately, other solutions yielded not the desired results, but using raycasting to trace the inside of the sink (and generate a new shape to function as a boolean) seems like a promising lead.

Comment: Did you try the solution proposed here of using an alpha map to "cut out" the top counter? https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-do-i-subtract-a-3d-sink-from-a-3d-cupboard-board/5527/3

Comment: The problem is that "various sinks" is not just a dozen or so but almost 2000 different models (though I concede that this wasn't clear in my original post).
I appreciate the input but I need a solution that ideally requires no manual adjusting for every other sink, which lead me to consider raycasting.